# Swift: Either/or lnitializer

Tags: swift, initialization

is there any way I can declare a Swift protocol where the implementing class should have an initializer that either takes a String or a Dictionary?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: As Swift is strongly typed I would advise against it - it would be better to have two initializers instead of having one initializer able to accept two specific types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best attempt would be something like this:

```
enum TextOrDict
{
    case Text(String)
    case Dict(Dictionary)
}

protocol MyProtocol
{
    init(value: TextOrDict)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    init(_ dictionary: Dictionary)
    init(_ string: String)
}
```

Technically, you will have two methods but the users will see it as one method.